# Trouble getting the correct color when summing RGB values

Tags: swift

I'm having a problem with a color mixing function in my iOS app. I have a function mixColors that takes an array of colors and should return their average color. However, I'm having trouble getting the correct result when I try to mix specific colors, such as yellow and blue.

Here's the mixColors function:

```swift
func mixColors() {
    mixedColor = nil
    var totalRed: CGFloat = 0
    var totalGreen: CGFloat = 0
    var totalBlue: CGFloat = 0
    
    for color in selectedColors {
        var internalColor = UIColor(color)
        var red: CGFloat = 0
        var green: CGFloat = 0
        var blue: CGFloat = 0
        var alpha: CGFloat = 0
        
        internalColor.getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)
    
        totalRed += red
        totalGreen += green
        totalBlue += blue
    }
    
    let count = CGFloat(selectedColors.count)
    
    let mixedRed = (totalRed / count)
    let mixedGreen = (totalGreen / count)
    let mixedBlue = (totalBlue / count)
    
    mixedColor = Color(UIColor(red: mixedRed, green: mixedGreen, blue: mixedBlue, alpha: 1.0))
}
```

When I try to mix yellow and blue, I expect to get green (0.0, 1.0, 0.392), but the result is `UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.5 0.639216 0.5 1`.

I would like to ask if someone can guide me on how to correctly sum the RGB values so that any combination of colors results in the correct color. How can I ensure that the sum of RGB values is accurate and produces the desired color?

Comment: Why do you think mixing yellow and blue would gets you green? Yellow is (1, 1, 0) and blue is (0, 0, 1). The average of their RGB values would be (0.5, 0.5, 0.5), which is almost you got. The actual numbers are a bit off probably because you are using the system colors, which aren't exactly (1, 1, 0) and (0, 0, 1).

Comment: @Sweeper What would be your recommendation, knowing that iOS gives me the RGB values from 0 to 1, green being let green = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 1.0, blue: 0.392)?

Comment: That does not answer my question - "Why do you think mixing yellow and blue would gets you green?"

Comment: have a look at these explanations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_mixing

Comment: I already make that of substraction in mixed green , mixed blue etc.. @workingdogsupportUkraine

Comment: If you want `UIColor.yellow` and `UIColor.blue` to be mixed to get green, then do your calculations with HSB components instead of RGB. `UIColor` has `getHue(_:saturation:brightness:alpha:)` for this. I was in the middle of providing a complete answer with updated code when the question was closed as a duplicate.

Comment: and there is a way in which it is a more general function where it adds colors and returns the correct answer, another example would be red but white would be pink, but it returns another different color. @HangarRash

Comment: @JaelRuvalcaba If you change your code to use hue/saturation/brightness as I suggested, mixing `UIColor.white` and `UIColor.red` does give you pink.

Comment: @HangarRash ok, it doesn't give me the color pink as such, it gives me one that's a bit similar, but in the same way if I add green with white, it should give me a lighter green, and it gives me orange, that's why I was wondering if there was a more general way.

Comment: @HangarRash I think you have a solution and my question has been reopened. Is there a general approach to mixing colors and displaying the result? For example, if I add a color to white, it should give me a lighter tone, and if I add a color to black, it should give me a darker tone. Also, if only two colors are selected, it should correctly display the resulting color they create. I understand this might seem more of a school style approach than how it's typically done in CS, but I'm curious to see if it can be achieved.

Comment: @JaelRuvalcaba I was finalizing my answer and including several examples when I discovered it actually only worked for a limited set of examples. I found that some color pairs gave good results when averaging the RGB values (a color with any shade of gray, for example). I found that some other color pairs gave good results when averaging the HSB values (yellow and blue -> green). But in general, some color pairs worked with RGB (blue and red -> purple) and some worked with HSB and I couldn't see how to choose which one to use. So sorry to get your hopes up.